# How could I add a simple delay in a Java Swing application?

Tags: java, multithreading, swing, timer, swingworker

I'd like to know how to add a time delay inside a Swing app in Java, I used `Thread.sleep(time)`, and also I used SwingWorker but it doesn't work. Here's part of my code:

```
switch (state) {
    case 'A':
        if (charAux == 'A') {
            state = 'B';                    
            //Here's where I'd like to add a time delay
            jLabel13.setForeground(Color.red);
            break;
        } else {                            
            //Here's where I'd like to add a time delay
            jLabel12.setForeground(Color.red);
            break;
        }
}
```

I hope you could help me or solve my doubts when I'm using SwingWorker.

Comment: Firstly, don't ever put a delay into the Event Dispatching Thread and always only update the UI from with the EDT. Secondly, I'd take a look at the [javax.swing.Timer](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/Timer.html) and [examples](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/timer.html)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here's an example using a `javax.swing.Timer`

```
public class TestBlinkingText {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
                } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
                } catch (InstantiationException ex) {
                } catch (IllegalAccessException ex) {
                } catch (UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
                }

                JFrame frame = new JFrame();
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                frame.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
                frame.add(new BlinkPane());
                frame.setSize(200, 200);
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }            
        });
    }

    protected static class BlinkPane extends JLabel {

        private JLabel label;
        private boolean state;

        public BlinkPane() {

            label = new JLabel("Look at me!");
            setLayout(new GridBagLayout());

            add(label);

            Timer timer = new Timer(500, new ActionListener() {

                @Override
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {                    
                    state = !state;
                    if (state) {
                        label.setForeground(Color.RED);
                    } else {
                        label.setForeground(Color.BLACK);
                    }                    
                    repaint();                    
                }
            });
            timer.setRepeats(true);
            timer.setCoalesce(true);
            timer.setInitialDelay(0);
            timer.start();            
        }        
    }    
}
```

Answer (score 7):

Good thing you removed the `Thread.sleep` as that would make your UI unresponsive for those 2 seconds.

What you can do is start a `Timer` which only runs once:

```
int delay = 2000;
Timer timer = new Timer( delay, new ActionListener(){
  @Override
  public void actionPerformed( ActionEvent e ){
    jLabel12.setForeground( Color.red );
  }
} );
timer.setRepeats( false );
timer.start();
```

Note that the `Timer` is a `javax.swing.Timer`, which assures that the `actionPerformed` method of the `ActionListener` is called on the Event Dispatch Thread, respecting the Swing threading rules.

This is also possible with a `SwingWorker`, but I would stick to the `Timer` for this. In case you want to use the `SwingWorker`, you can simply use `Thread.sleep` in the `doInBackground()` method, and update the `JLabel` in the `done()` method.

Something along the lines of

```
class Delay extends SwingWorker<Void, Object> {
 @Override
 public void doInBackground() {
  Thread.sleep( 2000 );
 }

 @Override
 protected void done() {
   jLabel12.setForeground( Color.red );
 }
}
```

Comment: @MadProgrammer but you provided a SSCCE, while I just provided some snippets (no need to fire up my IDE for that)

Comment: I should have a catalog of examples built up by now :P

Answer (score 2):

You'll want to use a [Timer](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/timer.html) if you want to specify a delay for an action.

Comment: a delay for a action, for example 2 seconds